# Count how many times strpos accured inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

How can i show how many times a sence was shown while looping?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($parts as $new[$i]) {

    $abouttoexpire = strpos($new[$i], 'Your Airbnb question is about to expire');
    $anairbnbexpert = strpos($new[$i], 'An Airbnb expert is waiting on feedback from you regarding');
    $requesttoalter = strpos($new[$i], 'Your request to alter reservation');

    //when the message was made
    preg_match('/<div class="timestamp"[\s\S]*?>(.*)*?\+0000<\/div>/', $new[$i], $dateofmsg);

    //between 9am and 6pm
    $hour = date('H', strtotime(@$dateofmsg[1]));
    if ($hour >= 9 && $hour <= 18) {

        //if we found this sentence
        if ($abouttoexpire !== FALSE) {
        //how i show here how many times we catch the sentence @abouttoexpire??
        }
    }
}
$i++;
```

Inside the condition: `if ($abouttoexpire !== FALSE)`
How do i print the times this sence (@abouttoexpire) was accured during the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;$j=0;
foreach ($parts as $new[$i]) {

  $abouttoexpire = strpos($new[$i], 'Your Airbnb question is about to expire');
  $anairbnbexpert = strpos($new[$i], 'An Airbnb expert is waiting on feedback from you regarding');
  $requesttoalter = strpos($new[$i], 'Your request to alter reservation');

  //when the message was made
  preg_match('/<div class="timestamp"[\s\S]*?>(.*)*?\+0000<\/div>/', $new[$i], $dateofmsg);

  //between 9am and 6pm
  $hour = date('H', strtotime(@$dateofmsg[1]));
  if ($hour >= 9 && $hour <= 18) {

    //if we found this sentence
    if ($abouttoexpire !== FALSE) {
      $j++;
    }
  }

 }
 $i++;

echo 'no_of_times:'.$j;
```

Comment: this is giving me no_of_times:0

Comment: why you need this $i++, its outside foreach..right?

Comment: it is needed because there are 3 loops there, but even without the $i what would change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $k = 0;
    foreach ($parts as $new[$i]) {

    if ($hour >= 9 && $hour <= 18) {

    $j++;

   if ($abouttoexpire !== FALSE) {

     $k++;

        }
    }
    $i++;
    }

    echo "foreach loop=".$i;
    echo "if loop =".$j;
     echo "within if loop =".$k;
```

Comment: where is the check the the phrase here?

Comment: I meant if ($abouttoexpire !== FALSE) I can see you added it to the code.. your solution is giving me:

foreach loop=1
if loop =0
within if loop =0
foreach loop=1
if loop =0
within if loop =0
foreach loop=1
if loop =0
within if loop =0
foreach loop=1
if loop =0
within if loop =0
foreach loop=1
if loop =1
within if loop =0
foreach loop=1
if loop =1
within if loop =0

But not exact number. perhaps because this is looping inside additional 2 foreach loops. but if i have about 20 strpos to check i will make 20 conditions and operator. it is not a good approach